# Regex to match spcific directory path but not others

Tags: regex

I have a file contains many lines.

For example:

```
HomeFolder=file:/user/local/home/joe/
HomeFolder=file:/user/local/home/max/
HomeFolder=file:/user/local/home/ted/
HomeFolder=file:/user/local/home/
HomeFolder=file:/user/local/
HomeFolder=file:/user/
HomeFolder=file:/
```

What I want is to match only the following lines:

```
HomeFolder=file:/user/local/home/
HomeFolder=file:/user/local/
HomeFolder=file:/user/
HomeFolder=file:/
```

Please help me come up with the regular expression that would achieve the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/TNatd6/2) will capture only the paths you want, and uses a `negative lookahead` to only capture if there aren't anymore subdirectories after `home/`

`^(HomeFolder=file:\/(?:user\/(?:local\/(?:home\/)?)?)?)(?!\w+\/)`